# Array based Binary Search out of bounds

Tags: java, arrays, file-io, binary-search-tree

The problem is I have an array based Binary search tree that needs to take in nearly 2000 lines of information from a text file read from a file IO.

However, I continuously get `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3012`.

I've attempted to make the array as large as I could without exceeding the limit in Java VM. But even that wasn't enough to store the file.

I tested with smaller files and it works fine.

Examples of the text files can be located at: https://www.asxhistoricaldata.com/

```
public class ArrayBinary implements Serializable
{
    private class Entry implements Serializable
    {
        private int key;
        private Object element;
        public Entry (int k, Object e)
        {
            this.key = k;
            this.element = e;
        }
    }
    private Entry [] tree;
    private int size;
    private int height;
    private int left;
    private int right;
    private static final int MAXCAPACITY =  2000;
    public ArrayBinary()
    {
        size = 0;
        height = 1;
        left = 0;
        right = 0;
        tree = new Entry[MAXCAPACITY];
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXCAPACITY; i++)
        {
            tree[i] = null;
        }
    }
    public void insert(int key, Object value)
    {
        size++;
        insert(key, value, 0);
    }
    public void insert (int key, Object value, int index)
    {
        boolean added = false;
        //System.out.println(key);
        if (tree[index] == null)
        {
            Entry node = new Entry(key, value);
            tree[index] = node;
            added = true;
        }
        else if (key < tree[index].key)
        {
            insert(key, value, index * 2 + 1);
        }
        else if (key == tree[index].key)
        {
            insert(key, value, index * 2 + 2);
        }
        else
        {
            insert(key, value, index * 2 + 2);
        }        
    }
}
```

this is what reads the files into the tree (just ignore the other two trees).

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TreeFileIO
{
    private BTree4 tempBt;
    private BinarySearchTree tempBst;
    private ArrayBinary tempArraybst;
    public Object read(String fileName, int type, int degree)
    {
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
                //degree is only needed for b-tree
                tempBt = new BTree4(degree);
                break;
            case 2:
                tempBst = new BinarySearchTree(); 
                break;
            case 3:
                tempArraybst = new ArrayBinary();
                break;
        }
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
        String line;
        int key;
        try
        {
            //open the file
            fileStrm = new FileInputStream (fileName + ".txt");
            InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm);
            BufferedReader bufRdr = new BufferedReader (rdr);
            line = bufRdr.readLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                switch(type)
                {
                    case 1:
                        tempBt.insert(getKey(line), line);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        tempBst.insert(getKey(line), line);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tempArraybst.insert(getKey(line), line);
                        break;
                }
                line = bufRdr.readLine();
            }
            //Closes the file once we're done
            fileStrm.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            if (fileStrm != null)
            {
                try 
                {
                    fileStrm.close();
                }
                catch (IOException ex2)
                {
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
        //Now send this tree to TreeProfiler for use
        switch(type)
        {
            case 1:
                return tempBt;                 
            case 2:
                return tempBst;    
            case 3:
                return tempArraybst;
        }
        return null;
    }
    //create a key using value from each line to avoid degenerate
    public int getKey(String csvRow)
    {
        StringTokenizer strTok = new StringTokenizer(csvRow, ",");
        int key = 0;
            try 
            {
                strTok.nextToken();
                strTok.nextToken();
                strTok.nextToken();
                strTok.nextToken();
                strTok.nextToken();
                strTok.nextToken();
                //Skip to last value to use as a key
               return key = Integer.parseInt(strTok.nextToken());
            }    
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                throw new IllegalStateException("CSV row had invalid format");
            }
    }
}
```

I expect the file to be read without reporting any array out of bounds and can hold an entire 2000 int file.

Comment: What data structure are you trying to use?  Balanced binary tree?  Unbalanced?  Your index always (more than) doubles, so you can reach an index of 2000 in as few as about 11 insertions.

Comment: I'm using Unbalanced, the code uses a balance scale to tell me the percentage of the balance(not in provided example).

Comment: Do you know the theoretical maximum depth for an unbalanced tree?

Comment: I know that for balanced it's O(log(N)) and unbalanced it's O(N).

Comment: So if it takes N levels and each level is 2**k in size, you would reach out to element 2**(N-1).  That's a very big array.

Comment: Well with the text file, the whole line is the Object Value and the last value in that line is the int key. Each file has around 1500-2000 lines of data.

Comment: Yeah but you don't have 2**2000 * `sizeof(Entry)` memory available, so maybe use a linked tree of references instead of an indexes into an array

Comment: I already have a node based Binary Search Tree, and I've been using that as a reference for this array based version. The assignment specifies I must have both types of trees. The node based version can handle the text files.

Comment: Could you give more information about the way you're filling the tree with the data? I believe you can solve the problem by just changing the order in which you take rows of the text file. But it would be easier to help you if you show the code that reads the text file and inserts data into the tree.

Comment: I've provided the file IO for the tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the fact that the data you are using seems to be ordered.

Filling a tree data structure by iterating over an ordered array of values will result in the tree devolving into a list, which is the reason you are getting those huge requirements of indices; every new item is added to the right side of the tree, resulting in indices continuously doubling.

The most efficient way to solve this problem is to fill the tree by taking the element in the middle of the data-set and then recursively repeating the process with the remaining two halves; the elements below and the ones above it. This way, the array will fill exactly.

Another alternative would be to take the elements in a random order from the data-set. In the average case, you may need more capacity than the 2000 you are providing but it may actually be feasible.

One final alternative would be to keep the same code and shuffle the data.

Since you are using a stream to read the CSV the first two solutions may be too complicated, so the best solution is to shuffle the lines of the text file and increasing the capacity of array. You can find various text file line shufflers online.

Comment: I think the shuffle is the best option because that was the one I was looking for, giving the array more capacity. But how would it look given the circumstances.

Comment: The code can remain the same. Just search for a text file shuffler online, input the contents of your CSV files (without the row with the column names if it has one), save the output and run the program with the new file. It may still need a bigger capacity but it can at least be feasible.

Comment: I don't know how to do that? sorry.

Comment: It's okay. Just go to the folder where you have the files, open one of them with a text editor, copy and paste all of the contents into a shuffler like this one: http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/shuffle-lines/ and then save the output in a new file. Finally use this new file with your program. Since the data is not longer ordered, the tree will not devolve into a list.

Comment: On second thought I don't think the shuffler is feasable because I'm not allowed to edit the files in anyway.

Comment: I think I'll have to do the recursive middle version.

Comment: I tried the maximum array length but it didn't work. I also changed the insert method to recursive.

Comment: I tested unit-conversion.info/texttools/shuffle-lines, and that method didn't work either, the only way I think I can get this code to work is to free up the capacity.